# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how to reset the db after each scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

So I am in my test environment

now, in the terminial, rake db:test:prepare clears the db... but not when i run it from the code

And I have this in features/support/env.rb:

```
Before do
    task :build_all do
      [ :debug, :release ].each do |t|
        $build_type = t
        Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].reenable
        Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].invoke
      end
    end
end
```

But my data remains in the project_test db when my tests are done running

This is in my database.yml

```
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: projectname_test
  username: root
  password:
```

Ive also tried

```
db:test:purge
```

and

```
db:test:reset
```

and I know that it is using my test db, because I check mySQLWorkbench, and it inserts data into the tables... but doesn't delete the data when its done (I have to delete it manually).
When the tables are empty, the test cases pass

Comment: Are you sure you are using Innodb and not MyISAM.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
begin
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."

end

Before do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

After do |scenario|
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Scenarios in Cucumber, like tests in RSpec, are run in transactions blocks and are rolled back once the scenario is done. Any data that's in the database that shouldn't be there is probably left over from something else. Try purging your database.

Comment: how? the Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
is in the env.rb...
so the transactions shold be working... but they aren't. there is data left over after I run cucumber features/featurename.feature

Answer (score 0):

Idk about this, but have you tried dropping and recreating the database on the fly?

Comment: didn't work =(  i did the same as above... except with 4 rake lines... with db:test:drop, and db:test:create

Comment: running Prepare in the terminal works... so I guess there is something wrong with the code in features/support/env.rb

Comment: Alright, maybe recoding (resolving the issue) in features/support/env.rb might be a solution.